# Does the warlock's Ghostly Gaze eldritch invocation automatically reveal hidden creatures?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, stealth, eldritch-invocations

Can a Warlock in D&D 5e with the Ghostly Gaze eldritch invocation automatically detect hidden creatures, considering that their cover is now transparent?

Is it even possible to hide from a Warlock with the Devil's Sight and Ghostly Gaze invocations?

Answer (score 7):

## It is still possible to hide from them

Starting with the wording of [Ghostly Gaze](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/xgte/subclasses#EldritchInvocations):

> As an action, you gain the ability to see through **solid objects to a range of 30 feet**. Within that range, you have darkvision if you don’t already have it. This special sight lasts for 1 minute or until your concentration ends (as if you were concentrating on a spell). During that time, you perceive objects as ghostly, transparent images.

And for [Devil's Sight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#EldritchInvocations-388):

> You can see normally in darkness, both magical and nonmagical, to a distance of 120 feet.

Both effects only work together out to 30 feet, so being outside that means you can at least still use cover to hide. Within that range, if you are concealed by darkness and/or cover behind a solid object, then you would no longer be hidden to them.

Within that range there are still other ways to hide however. Here's a few examples:

- You could be [Invisible](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Invisible)
- You could blind the Warlock by some other means, such as the *[Blindness/Deafness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/blindness-deafness)* spell
- You could hide behind a non-solid obscuration, such as the *[Fog Cloud](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fog-cloud)* spell, or in a murky liquid
- You could hide behind illusions, such as those created by the *[Silent Image](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/silent-image)* spell
- You could hide behind a creature ([since creatures are not objects](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/114722/is-there-anything-that-is-simultaneously-a-creature-and-an-object))

Comment: Good answer, but I'd be careful of the illusions thing.  If illusions are not made transparent by Ghostly Gaze, then Ghostly Gaze turns into a form of truesight (and an interesting effect of that is that they are then discerned as illusions and become transparent, lol.)

Answer (score 0):

## Cover is not necessary to hide

The rules for [Hiding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#Hiding) state:

> You can't hide from a creature that can see you **clearly**
>
> ...
>
> **What Can You See?** One of the main factors in determining whether you can find a hidden creature or object is how well you can see in an area, which might be lightly or heavily obscured

Normally when a creature hides behind an object they have complete concealment. Any attempt to locate them with sight fails. But this doesn't actually cause any disadvantage most of the time. The locating creature uses their normal perception score, because they can still hear or otherwise sense the creature.

### You can hide in line of sight

In many situations you can hide in direct line of sight. For example in fog, dim light, heavy shadows, rain, foliage, darkness, etc. The key is not to be clearly visible.

Even if the Warlock can see through the crate that a Goblin is hiding behind, they may not even be able to distinguish the Goblin from the "ghostly, transparent images". It is up to your DM to decide.

### Darkvision isn't all that useful for locating hidden foes

As above, locating a hidden foe is not a sight based check, it is a combination of all senses. Darkvision doesn't give any advantage.

The rules for [vision and light](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#VisionandLight) state:

> A given area might be lightly or heavily obscured. In a lightly obscured area, such as **dim light**, patchy fog, or moderate foliage, creatures have **disadvantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on sight**.

They go on to explain how Darkvision works:

> Many creatures in fantasy gaming worlds, especially those that dwell underground, have darkvision. Within a specified range, a creature with darkvision can see in darkness **as if the darkness were dim light**, so areas of darkness are only lightly obscured as far as that creature is concerned. However, the creature can't discern color in darkness, only shades of gray.

Unfortunately, having disadvantage on sight is a clear indication that you cannot see "clearly". Sure, it's better than automatically failing vision checks, but like I said, you probably don't have to rely purely on vision. Darkvision is at disadvantage, so it is strictly worse than just listening.

### Devil's Sight is better than Darkvision, but it's still only niche

Luckily Devil's Sight is not Darkvision, but that only helps if an enemy is hiding only in the shadows. If they are hiding behind something, or in fog, then it makes no difference.