# Do the Thunder Gauntlets and Lightning Launchers of Adamantine Arcane Armor count as Adamantine weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, armor, artificer, special-materials

As stated in Xanathar's Guide:

> Adamantine is an ultrahard metal found in meteorites and extraordinary mineral veins. In addition to being used to craft adamantine armor, the metal is also used for weapons. Melee weapons and ammunition made of or coated with adamantine are unusually effective when used
> to break objects. Whenever an adamantine weapon or piece of ammunition hits an object, the hit is a critical hit.

Armorer's Arcane Armor and 14th Lv Arcane Propulsion Armor Infusion states:

> Each model includes a special weapon. When you attack with that weapon, you can add your Intelligence modifier, instead of Strength or Dexterity, to the attack and damage rolls.

> Thunder Gauntlets. Each of the armor's gauntlets counts as a simple melee weapon while you aren't holding anything in it, and it deals 1d8 thunder damage on a hit. A creature hit by the gauntlet has disadvantage on attack rolls against targets other than you until the start of your next turn, as the armor magically emits a distracting pulse when the creature attacks someone else.

> Lightning Launcher: A gemlike node appears on one of your armored fists or on the chest (your choice). It counts as a simple ranged weapon, with a normal range of 90 feet and a long range of 300 feet, and it deals 1d6 lightning damage on a hit. Once on each of your turns when you hit a creature with it, you can deal an extra 1d6 lightning damage to that target.

> 14th Lv Arcane Propulsion Armor:
> The armor includes gauntlets, each of which is a magic melee weapon that can be wielded only when the hand is holding nothing. The wearer is proficient with the gauntlets, and each one deals 1d8 force damage on a hit and has the thrown property, with a normal range of 20 feet and a long range of 60 feet. When thrown, the gauntlet detaches and flies at the attack's target, then immediately returns to the wearer and reattaches.

Lightning Launcher was never specified that it fires projectiles but safe to say Adamatine's auto-crit-on-hit should not work for it. But however does any armor of Adamantine as an Armorer's Arcane Armor now qualifies as both weapon and armor or is it separate (all but gauntlets is armor and the gauntlets the weapon)? Are the Thunder Gauntlets and Arcane Propulsion Armor (Rocket Punch) allowed to have the auto-crit-on-hit that adamantine weapons do?

Comment: Interesting question. Could you clarify what the armor is "hitting" in this example? Like, are you asking about someone trying to bash down a door, or are you asking about striking an enemy with your gauntlets. I ask because you describe the adamantine armor as having an "auto-crit-on-hit" feature, which seems to imply that this works whenever they hit anything.

Comment: Xanathar's guide states: "Whenever an adamantine weapon or piece of ammunition hits an object, the hit is a critical hit" It never specifically said what said object is. I figure anything you hit with it is a critical hit.

Comment: See, your use of the term "anything" here makes me unsure how you're reading that. Let's be clear: are you asking if this would apply to creatures you are fighting? Like, for example, a wolf?

Answer (score 5):

#### It probably works on the thunder gauntlets.

The rules for adamantine weapons state:

> Whenever an adamantine weapon or piece of ammunition hits an object, the hit is a critical hit.

Arcane Armor states:

> It also expands to cover your entire body, although you can retract or deploy the helmet as a bonus action.

And finally, Thunder Gauntlets states:

> Each of the armor’s gauntlets counts as a simple melee weapon

So a thunder gauntlet is an adamantine melee weapon, so hit with thunder gauntlets against objects are automatic criticals. Lightning Launcher is a ranged weapon, so it does not work.

Note, the automatic critical feature of adamantine weapons *only applies when attacking objects, not creatures*.

Comment: It should be really clarified a bit more "object' are just about anything. In animate object, non-living things and the like would be more clearer. Or just plain say Adamatine is good for sundering since you tech can't sunder a living being.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver The primary relevant mechanical distinction is between objects and creatures. An object is usually anything that is not a creature. Adamantine weapons definitively do not get automatic criticals on any creatures.

Comment: Then by that definition, Golems, and clockwork creatures are objects right?

Comment: No, [they are creatures, not objects](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/114722/is-there-anything-that-is-simultaneously-a-creature-and-an-object).

Answer (score 1):

If it can apply at all the Adamantine weapon rules would only apply to the Thunder Gauntlets, you could not apply Arcane Propulsion Armor to Adamantine armor ever. While you are not restricted from any armor being turned into your Arcane Armor, your infusions can only be applied to mundane items which makes them magical. Since Adamantine Armor is listed as magic armor it cannot take an infusion