# Can the Message cantrip be used to communicate with a sentient object?

Tags: dnd-5e, targeting, cantrips, intelligent-magic-items

Can the *Message* cantrip be used to communicate with a sentient object?

I just want some clarification, since my DM gave me a sentient staff and my character only really communicates through the *message* cantrip.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### The Message cantrip must target a creature

This is spelled out in the [spell's description](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/message) (emphasis mine):

> You point your finger toward a **creature** within range and whisper a message. The target (and only the target) hears the message and can reply in a whisper that only you can hear.

A magic item (even a sentient one) is not considered a creature but an object. You can see these related questions for details on the distinction:

- [What is the definition of “creature” and is it used consistently?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47254/33707)
- [What is considered an object?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/95532/33707)

Therefore, the Message cantrip can't be used to communicate with a sentient item.

### Other ways to communicate with sentient magic items

The DMG has a [section on sentient magic items](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/sentient-magic-items-artifacts#CreatingSentientMagicItems). This section includes tables with the kinds of ways a sentient magic item might be able to communicate and the kind of senses it has which allow someone to communicate with it.