# Does a sentient magic item count as a creature for the purpose of spells like Scrying?

Tags: dnd-5e, targeting, intelligent-magic-items

I'm curious if a sentient magic item can be counted as a creature for spells such as *Scrying*.

Comment: Welcome to the stack! Please take our [tour] to learn more about how we operate and you can also visit the [help] for more information.

Comment: I'm going to edit out the second question, as that's idea generation which we really don't do here. You can absolutely visit our very own [chat] to discuss, or visit one of our curated [forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No, it can not be by RAW

The [Scrying](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scrying) spell states (emphasis mine)

> You can see and hear a particular **creature** you choose that is on the
> same plane of existence as you. The target must make a Wisdom saving
> throw, which is modified by how well you know the target and the sort
> of physical connection you have to it. If a target knows you're
> casting this spell, it can fail the saving throw voluntarily if it
> wants to be observed.

and moreover

> Instead of targeting a creature, you can choose a **location** you have
> seen before as the target of this spell. When you do, the sensor
> appears at that location and doesn't move.

By RAW, the target should be either a creature or a location, not an item, even if it is a sentient magic one.

Moreover, the section of sentient magic items in DMG does not mention this possibility. In the 3rd paragraph (pag 214) you can find nonetheless

> Sentient magic items function as NPCs under the DM's control.

It seems that this may allow one to consider a sentient item as a creature, since it is written that it functions as an NPC, but actually this sentence is just for the DM, in order to give directions on how to rule these items in game.

Indeed, there are other spells that support the above reading of the rules:

- [Locate Object](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/locate-object) and [Locate Creature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/locate-creature), for example, that are specifically designed for items and creature, respectively. Moreover, *Locate Creature* says (emphasis mine):

> If the creature you described or named is in a *different form*, such as
> being under the effects of a polymorph spell, this spell doesn't
> locate the creature.

Hence, if a creature is transformed into an object via [True Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph), the spell fails because the target is in a different form.

- [True Seeing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-seeing) that allows to see items and creatures by [truesight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Truesight) (emphasis mine):

> A monster with truesight can, out to a specific range, see in normal
> and magical darkness, see invisible creatures **and** objects,
> automatically detect visual illusions and succeed on saving throws
> against them, and perceive the original form of a shapechanger or a
> creature that is transformed by magic. Furthermore, the monster can
> see into the Ethereal Plane within the same range.

- [See Invisibility](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/see-invisibility) explicit mentions creatures *and* object:

> For the duration, you see invisible creatures and objects as if they
> were visible, and you can see into the Ethereal Plane. Ethereal
> creatures and objects appear ghostly and translucent.

These spells make explicit their targets: creatures, items or both.

Comment: @Kirt It is true that there is no definition of **creature** in DMG, nor in PHB nor in MM, or at least I did not find any...

Comment: And see: [What is the definition of “creature” and is it used consistently?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47254/what-is-the-definition-of-creature-and-is-it-used-consistently)

Comment: @Kirt I added some more details in my answer, as suggested: I hope that I have clarified a little bit more. Thanks!

Comment: Not only clearer now, but a more convincing argument, particularly the part about True Polymorph and Locate Creature.  Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

### As Written: No.

An object may have certain qualities which make it seem like a creature, however, it is still an object. In the magical world of DnD some objects can speak, move around, and every have an embedded consciousness. But until they are given a full stat block identifying them as a creature, they are still an object.

For example, in the DMG creation rules states:

> If you determine these characteristics randomly, ignore or adapt any result that doesn’t make sense for an inanimate object.

Indicating it is still, an inanimate object, despite its unique qualities.

That said, there is at least 1 sentient item in which the consciousness can be released into a full creature.

> The Shield of the Hidden Lord in Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus.

Finally as a DM you always have the option to allow spells to work even if they do not mechanically work as written. For example, many cantrips only target creatures, however it is not uncommon for DMs to allow you to say "Eldritch Blast" a door or window.

Comment: If you can convince them to cast Animate Objects on the sentient item first....

Comment: Can you add some support to the statements you make in your answer?

Comment: That an object is an object? I can try..

Comment: That a sentient item is an object and object only, and which sentient item can be released into a full creature? If you are recommending the DM do this for a sentient item, it would also be helpful to discuss the pitfalls of doing so